styled-components no longer works with react-native: "0.72.2"
{
"name": "teste",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start --dev-client",
"android": "expo run:android",
"ios": "expo run:ios",
"web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
"expo": "~51.0.20",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
},
"private": true
}
When installing the styled-components library packages I receive the following error "npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: teste@1.0.0
npm error found: react@18.2.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm error peer react@">= 16.8.0" from styled-components@6.1.12
npm error node_modules/styled-components
npm error styled-components@"" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.3.1" from react-dom@18.3.1
npm error node_modules/react-dom
npm error peer react-dom@">= 16.8.0" from styled-components@6.1.12
npm error node_modules/styled-components
npm error styled-components@"" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error /Users/barranco/.npm/_logs/2024-07-19T19_22_58_297Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/barranco/.npm/_logs/2024-07-19T19_22_58_297Z-debug-0.log" I've already tried using several versions of node and none of them worked, currently I have node v18.20.4

As found by the question author themself MuriloBarranco.
To fix the error, follow the steps below:

rm -r node_modules inside your directory.
Add styled components to package.json


Open your package.json file and add the following line to the dependencies section "styled-components": "^5.1.1"


Update the React-DOM Version


In the package.json file, check the dependencies section
Replace the react-dom line with the following, using your current React version ("react-dom": "<YOUR CURRENT REACT VERSION>")


After all of this reinstall all of your dependencies (npm install)

Credit goes to the question author.
